# Getting a "waterfall" effect from 2d image only facing one direction, not wrapping

Tags: texturing

[>>PROJECT FILE HERE <<](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Q0NVCWwG7ctqbwBsYobHRHynYZPaU-5/view?usp=sharing)

I took a look in search but I guess I didn't put in the proper search terms because I got a whole lot of results unrelated. I'm 100% sure this has been asked before but I just can't find it.

Basically I want to apply this image to the entire building in a way that it wraps around with the same sizes, consistently. However, I'd think I wouldn't have to unwrap the whole model to do so, right?

[image: Current Nodes][image: Another shot][image: Texture put in, creating "waterfall" or stretch, no wrapping]
[image: original 2D texture]

[image]

Comment: A simple solution without unwrapping would be to set the _Image Texture_ projection to _Box_ instead of the default _Flat_. After changing to _Box_ there will appear an option _Blend_, you can set this to > 0 if you don't want too sharp transitions on the edges.

Comment: You need to UV unwrap, or for this model a method like triplanar projection might work.

Comment: @AllenSimpson That's why I said use _Box_  ;-)  I guess not every beginner will realize that the _Box_ projection in the _Image Texture_ node is triplanar projection.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I use it all the time with the blend option for quick rocks, it's great

Comment: @AllenSimpson Yeah sure, never doubted that... I just meant saying "triplanar projection might work" could be difficult for beginners because some might not know what that is and it's not called liked that in the _Image Texture_ node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using *Object* texture coordinates, and your shape is rather "boxy" I think you could get away with using *Box* projection (instead of *Flat*):

[image: Box]

Comment: THAT'S what that BOX/SPHERE/TUBE stuff is for eh? thanks!

Comment: Yes, it creates an imaginary bounding box around your object for whatever shape you choose and uses that to make the texture projection calculations. Default is flat, because most people use UV coordinates for image textures and they're 2D (X&Y only - ie. "flat").